# Функция RTRIM() в Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Встречал функцию `trim()` в языках программирования. Эта функция удаляла пробелы в начале и в конце строки. В книге по Postgresql прочитал:

> `RTRIM()` для удаления пробелов в конце строки

Почему в Postgresql для удаления пробелов в конце строки? А в начале?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно где есть `RTRIM` (обрезка справа), там есть и `LTRIM` (обрезка слева). А в PostgreSQL есть еще и `BTRIM` (обрезка с обоих сторон).

> PostgreSQL дает вам функции `LTRIM`, `RTRIM()` и `BTRIM`, которые являются более короткими аналогами функции `TRIM()`.
>
> Функция `LTRIM()` удаляет все символы, (пробелы, по умолчанию), с начала строки.
> Функция`RTRIM()` удаляет все символы, (пробелы, по умолчанию), с конца строки.
> Функция `BTRIM()` это комбинация `LTRIM()` и `RTRIM()`.

Вот тут все подробно расписано на англ. - http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-trim-function/

---

*Как дополняет Akina:*

Исторически сначала существовала только `TRIM` (это относится скорее к тем временам, когда про СУБД ещё никто особо и не думал). Потом хотелки юзеров потребовали удаления не всего, а откуда хочется, и были сформированы `LTRIM` (left trim), `RTRIM` (right trim) и BTR`I`M (both trim). Последняя фактически является алиасом старой `TRIM`, и введена скорее для подобия имён, чем по делу. В других языках и SQL-диалектах оно может быть и по-другому (скажем, в MySQL функция одна, но зато есть параметры `LEADING`, `TRAILING` и `BOTH`) - в общем, дело вкуса разработчика.

Comment: Можно перевод, не для меня, а возможно для других кто встретиться с этой проблемой, благодарю

Comment: А какая тогда разница между BTRIM() и просто TRIM()? Одно и тоже, а зачем тогда вообще BTRIM() придумали?

Comment: @MikeMclaren Исторически сначала существовала только TRIM. Потом хотелки юзеров потребовали удаления не всего, а откуда хочется, и были сформированы LTRIM (left trim), RTRIM (right trim) и BTRIM (both trim). Последняя фактически является алиасом старой TRIM, и введена скорее для подобия имён, чем по делу. В других языках и SQL-диалектах оно может быть и по-другому (скажем, в MySQL функция одна, но зато есть параметры LEADING, TRAILING и BOTH) - в общем, дело вкуса разработчика.

Comment: Да не вопрос, конечно. А на ответ тут явно не набирается... только следует оговорить, что "Исторически сначала существовала только TRIM." относится скорее к тем временам, когда про СУБД ещё никто особо и не думал.

Comment: TRIM не _"старая"_, TRIM - это SQL-стандарт (LEADING, TRAILING и BOTH, кстати, оттуда же). Если СУБД, кроме прочего, реализует стандарт - это всегда плюс.

Comment: @Kromster поздравляю с Юбилеем, 10000 репутации, всё благодаря моему вопросу)))

Comment: @MikeMclaren спасибо, это все Akina помог ;-)